# Help finding the perimeter of a circumscribed hexagon

Tags: geometry

> Two equilateral triangles are circumscribed about the same circle such
>   that their intersection is a regular hexagon (see picture below). If
>   the radius of the circle is $10$, find the area and the perimeter of the hexagon.
>
> [image]

Here's my attempt:

I know that the sum of the angles of the hexagon is $(n-2)180=4*180º=720º$. So each angle has measure $720º/6=120º$.

[image]

If I could show that angle $∠ AMO=∠ ABO=90º$, from a theorem presented previously in the book, it would follow that point $O$ lies on the bisector of $∠ A$. From there I think I can find $|AC|$ and hence the perimeter and area of the hexagon. I'm not sure how to go about showing that tough. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use that $$\tan(30^{\circ})=\frac{x}{r}$$ and $$\tan(30^{\circ})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: `If I could show that angle ∠AMO=∠ABO=90º` The triangles are circumscribed to the circle, so $\,M,B\,$ are presumably the tangency points. Then use that [Tangent - Perpendicular to Radius](https://brilliant.org/wiki/tangent-perpendicular-to-radius/).